# Cannot locate elements inside Microsoft HTML Component

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, automation

I am trying to automate a really old website that uses the Microsoft HTML Components framework and runs only on Internet explorer. I am using IEServerDriver.

Certain components within the page are loaded from a `.htc` file. Note that these are not in an iframe. So I cannot *switch* to it. As you can see in the image, they are loaded in a separate html tag below the first one. **The issue is that I am not able to locate anything inside the component.**

[image]
In the image you can see a div with the id `theTree_Root`. Trying to get this element with

```
driver.find_element_by_id("theTree_Root")
```

will just fail. I did also try to wait for elements inside this component (just times out). Even a hard-coded sleep did not work.

Comment: Update the question with text based HTML and the error stack trace.

Comment: Which version of IE and IE Driver are you using? Is there any error message after running the code? If possible, you could provide the link of the website. Or you could provide the html structure of the page using text not picture. Beside, please provide [a minimal, reproducible code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test.